# Retrieve 'date and time' for Facebook shares and likes?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page

Is it possible to track the number of likes of a Fan page status in a certain interval of time, let's say in a month?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what you want to achieve is just not available through the present Facebook APIs. The data regarding to likes and shares that you can retrieve about the post is just limited to `array` of likes with just `id` and `name` and `shares` array with `count`